# Entity framework and stored procedure with output parameter returning row (EF will receive complex type)

Tags: stored-procedures, row, entity-framework-6, complextype, output-parameter

I am using entity framework 6 with stored procedures. Currently I deal with this problem:

Ideally I need to get data from one stored procedure. This data includes:
One Conversation (basic info) + multiple Clients (which are engaged in this conversation) + Messages from Conversation.

I think that output parameters is right way to do, but i am stuck.

So, how can I do that? And is this the right way to get rows of different data from stored procedure? I am trying to avoid a solution where I would be sending recurring data about conversation with every row of the client.

Answer (score 0):

I found alternative solution with multiple result sets [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx) and [here (imho better)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675933/Returning-Multiple-Result-Sets-from-an-Entity-Fram), but this is not the answer to my question..

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (SchoolEntities context = new SchoolEntities())
  {
    var outputParameter = new ObjectParameter(“sum”, typeof(decimal));
    context.SchoolBudgetForDateRange(new DateTime(2007, 1, 1), 
      new DateTime(2008, 1, 1), 
      outputParameter);
    Console.WriteLine(outputParameter.Value);
  }
}
```

where SchoolBudgetForDateRange is a stored procedure

more info [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/05/09/how-to-retrieve-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-entity-framework/)